# trying to get all p tag text between two h2 tags

Tags: xpath

```
<h2><span>Title1</span></h2>
<p>text I want</p>
<p>text I want</p>
<p>text I want</p>
<p>text I want</p>
<h2>Second Title I want to stop collecting p tags after</h2>
```

I can get p tags by identifying the text within the h2, then get preceeding-sibling::p but this grabs all p tags to the end of the DOM.  I have tried to use the "and" selector to essentially declare a start and end but it returns null.   I must be missing something here but I've been stuck on this for quite a while.  I cannot predict how many p tags I need so an index number on the p element is not going to help me in this case.

Here is the xpath I used to get all of the following p tags after an h2.  the problem is it grabs all p tags to the end of the DOM.

```
//span[contains(text(), "Title1")]/ancestor::h2/following-sibling::p
```

Comment: "I can get p tags by identifying the text within the h2, then get preceeding-sibling::p" - Can you show the XPath that you have tried there, please?

Comment: thank you, I just edited the question to include the xpath I used which is grabbing more than I need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So you just want to get all the `p` tags where they are between two specific `h2` tags.  The xpath query is exactly as it sounds.

```
//p[
   preceding-sibling::h2[span='Title1'] and
   following-sibling::h2[.='Second Title I want to stop collecting p tags after']
]
```

The query could be simplified by selecting all `p` where the first preceding `h2` element is the starting element.  In other words, there are no other `h2` previous siblings between the current `p` and the header.

```
//p[preceding-sibling::h2[1][span='Title1']]
```

Comment: Just one other question, what if I do not know what the text is going to be in the second h2?  I've tried to just say h2[1], but it specifically wants and ending h2 with exact text.

Comment: I'm not sure how to formulate a query to go up to just the next "h2", normally this is where I would use non-xpath code to do the filtering. But I'll see if I can cook one up.